# How to work Haptic Feedback on AVcaptureSession is running

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I want to create UX like iOS14 video camera.
It have vibration when record button is tapped.

I know the way to vibrate short time using UINotificationFeedbackGenerator()

[Swift : Make a very short vibration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604087/swift-make-a-very-short-vibration)

But it is not worked if captureSession have audio input.

[How can I play a haptic feedback while AvCapture Session is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582128/how-can-i-play-a-haptic-feedback-while-avcapture-session-is-running)

This code is worked but it have blackout phase when it working. So not good enough.

[UIImpactFeedbackGenerator Not Working When Audio Device Added to AVCaptureSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46750361/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator-not-working-when-audio-device-added-to-avcapturesessio)

```
self.session.stopRunning()
    // Play haptic
    UINotificationFeedbackGenerator().notificationOccurred(.warning)
    // Not completely sure if this delay is needed but you might need to wait until the run loop after the haptic plays to resume capture session
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
        self.session.startRunning()
}
```

It is really helpful if let me know how to work Haptic Feedback on AVcaptureSession.

Comment: You already shared the answer, yes? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57743674/3231194

Comment: Thanks! But no..
I understood as AVCaptureSession prevent haptic feedback.
And if microphone is not recording haptic will work.

But microphone is automatically woking if I add AudioInput on AVCaptureSession.
And  it will be blackout if I remove AudioInput from AVCaptureSession.

I don't know how to stop microphone recording on AVCaptureSession without blackout..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haptic feedback not playing nice with AVFoundation? (UIImpactFeedbackGenerator, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44212923/haptic-feedback-not-playing-nice-with-avfoundation-uiimpactfeedbackgenerator)